# Can't recuperate the css and javascript magento 2

Tags: magento2

I put my site on virtual machine and i executed all the necessary permisssions also reindexed the site and flush cache and `deploy_static` but no result i get those error  instead

> requested URL
>   /site/pub/static/version1543486866/adminhtml/Sm/shop4u/fr_FR/jquery/jstree/themes/default/style.css
>   was not found on this server

(for all css and some javascript) please any advice ?? and thanks in advance

Comment: In your pub/static folder .htaccess file exist ?

Comment: yes it exist  in pub/static

Comment: clear all folder in Var directory except .htacces file and apply upgrade,compile and deploy command and check

Comment: i did that but no result :(